# Checking if all values in one array exist in another array

Tags: php

I am trying to check if all required values exist in an array. I thought using `array_intersect` would be what I should be using:

```
$required[0] = 'FirstName';
$required[1] = 'LastName';

$posted['Email'] = 'none@example.com';
$posted['FirstName'] = 'Bob';
$posted['Group'] = '5';

print_r(array_intersect($required, $posted));
```

So, I want to be sure that "FirstName" and "LastName" exist in the `$posted` array. However, "LastName" is missing, but this returns an empty array result.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$posted` originally comes from `$_POST` at some point, (as in the values from inputs on a form), all of the keys will be set, even though some may be set to `''`. Since you have keys as values in your `$required` array, It's probably best to just check the required fields in a loop. You can use `empty` to simultaneously verify that they exist and have truthy values. Assuming the following code is the body of a function or the contents of a file, something like this should work:

```
foreach ($required as $requirement) {
    // if everything has to have a value, just return false as soon as something doesn't
    if (empty($posted[$requirement]) return false;
}
return true;
```

Part of why the way you're doing it with `array_intersect` isn't working because that function will check the values in `$required` against the values in `$posted`, and you need to check the values in `$required` against the *keys* in `$posted`. The other part is that `array_intersect` will return the values that the two arrays have in common, not the ones that are missing.

If some of the keys in `$posted` really may not exist, it may be better to define your `$required` array by key instead of by value, and then use `array_diff_key`.

```
$required['FirstName'] = true;
$required['LastName'] = true;

$missing_requirements = array_diff_key($required, $posted);
```

If every key in `$required` is present in `$posted`, the result will be an empty array, which will evaluate to `false`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm surprised that I'm finding that just checking `if (empty())...` for all the required fields is about 50% faster on average. I thought this would be much faster.

Comment: Well, it has the advantage of no function calls, and if you do it like I suggested, you don't actually have to look through everything, you can stop looking as soon as you find one missing thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r(array_intersect($required, array_keys($posted)));
```

Simple solution:

```
if (count(array_intersect($required, array_keys($posted))) == count($required) ) { 
return true;
} else {
return false;
}
```

Comment: This returns all of the values in `$required` that exist in `$posted`. I basically just need to return `true` if all exist or `false` if not.

Comment: If (count(array_intersect($required, array_keys($posted))) == count($required) ) { return true;} else {return false;} @JROB

Comment: count is no good if you are matching array values that could have different results and the array count gets changed dynamically.